# WCF Data Service Change Tracking: How to cancel save changes and revert to original values for an object

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata, change-tracking

I have a WCF Data Service that is wrapping an Entity Framework 4 data model. I am connecting a WPF client to the service using the WCF Data Services Client library.

Is it possible in WCF Data Services to undo / cancel changes to tracked objects ?

scenario : In the UI I allow a user to edit an object. I have save and cancel buttons. If the user chooses to save I call SaveChanges() on my WCF context and changes are sent to the database via the WCF service. If the user clicks cancel I want to undo the changes and revert to the original property values of the current object.

I know that the WCF data services client library has change tracking built in - but I cannot find any way at accessing this information.

In Entity Framework the context supports the Refresh method and you can specify RefreshMode.StoreWins and pass in the object - this will effectively cancel / undo any changes.
documented here  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx

Any suggestions on how I can achieve the same thing in WCF DataServices in my client application ?

cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1):

The only "solution" I know of is:

```
var oldMergeOption = _service.MergeOption;
_service.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
try {
    _service.YourQueryable.Where(x => x.Id==oldObject.Id).Single();
} finally {
    _service.MergeOption = oldMergeOption;
}
```

This should replace the values of "oldObject" with the values stored in the DB. However, I'm not sure if the object returned by Single() will always be the same as "oldObject".

Comment: FYI: I currently work around this problem using a BindingGroup with BeginEdit, CancelEdit, and (ValidateWithoutUpdate and) CommitEdit. Just do a BeginEdit in the DataContextChanged event and a CancelEdit in the Cancel buttons Click-Event. In the OK buttons Click-Event, try a validation first (ValidateWithoutUpdate) and the execute a CommitEdit when the validation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I typically refrain from operating on entities within the DataServiceContext until I'm ready to commit those changes to the database.  I don't treat my entities as part of my domain model so I create a specific domain model that adapts my model objects to entity objects using adapters and a repository class.  This way, all operations within by domain model are self-contained until I'm ready to commit them to the database.  A fantastic article from Ben Day on what I'm referring to can be found here: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/04/01/pfcov_silverlight-mvvm-tips.aspx